# IE Hack how to make IE to skip/avoid from reading a line in the style sheet

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to make Internet Explorer skip or avoid reading a line in the CSS stylesheet?

I'm mostly concerned with IE8, but interested in solutions for any version.

Comment: sure, but you will have to be more specific, what version of IE?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: @Madmartigan: I have. Please read the link. Scroll down. 'Hacks'.

Comment: @JanHančič I assume OP wants to target IE8 and older versions, since he tagged the question with `internet-explorer-8`.

Comment: @Konerak: OK I see, you suggest loading an entirely separate stylesheet just for non-IE browsers? Seems like overkill. Maybe a little more context with your comment/link would be useful.

Comment: @ jan Hancic: i m using  version 8

Comment: @Madmartigan: you can, but if you read the article, you will see they also offer ways to just enable/disable one CSS block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent IE8 (and older) from reading the styles, simply use something in your selector that it doesn’t support and that all other browsers support.

For example, add `:root` to your selector. Here’s an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/kX6tR/

```
.foo { background: red; }
:root .foo { background: lime; }
```

`:root` is supported in IE9 and all other browsers, therefore this is a [safe CSS hack](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#safe-css-hacks).

Comment: Nice, was just about to suggest the exact same thing. No need for hacks here.

Comment: This is one of the most useful "hacks" I've seen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is always better to avoid hacks altogether. The right thing to do in your case is re-define your CSS rule for IE in a separate stylesheet and include it after the main style file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nice_browsers.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dumb_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In addition normal browsers will not download the second file, so no extra HTTP request. And the main CSS file will validate (if you care about that - and you probably should)

Comment: It is always better to avoid hacks altogether. True, but who is suggesting or requesting a "hack"?

Comment: @Madmartigan The hack is hack, even if it's considered "safe". You're right and Mathias Bynens' solution is absolutely OK. The only issue with hacks - they work today, but tomorrow they might break or behave in some unexpected way. But that's just "might" :)

Comment: Traditional IE hacks relied on a busted parser and invalid CSS. I can think of this though: there are probably other browsers that don't support `:root` which will get hit by the "IE" rule unintentionally, so in that sense I see how it's a hack, but I doubt very much that IE8 will suddenly start supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

another option:

Let IE read the line in your stylesheet, and then overwrite the line in an ie specific stylesheet loaded afterwards by using a conditional comment:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

that way you get to keep your stylesheets free from selector hacks.

Comment: +0 Conditional CSS files are a maintenance nightmare and we have other hack-free options.

Comment: Using separate IE-specific stylesheets is a very bad idea. Reasons: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks

Comment: @Madmartigan - Old IE makes CSS a maintenance nightmare :) I find conditional stylesheets easier to manage, since you know where to go looking if IE has an issue, without having to dig through a stylesheet contents looking for hacks.

Comment: @Evert: There are alternatives: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: @Madmartigan, for the record: I don't use any hacks or conditional comments since our company dropped < IE7 support, there is always a way to avoid them. I really like that paulirish solution though!